# Sendmail_from function in php.ini

Tags: email, .htaccess, configuration, php, bluehost

I currently own a hosting package with `Bluehost.com`. All emails sent from any mail function end up sending in the  `username@boxname.bluehost.com`. I tried editing a `php.ini` file for this. It still didn't work.

I am running WordPress. When new users are registered, they are emailed with this bluehost formatted email address.

What exactly can I do?

Answer (score 1):

How do you send the emails? I assume using [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) PHP function and not special class like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.sourceforge.net/)?

If so -- you should manually provide proper `From: "Your Name" <email@example.com>` field in `$additional_headers` parameter -- worked fine for me so far (I've been using it on GoDaddy and Webfusion UK hosting).

Answer (score 1):

This stumped me recently. This is caused by something Bluehost does to prevent you from spamming/phishing and claiming you're someone you're not. If the script you're using claims a from address that isn't configured in your Bluehost account, they won't let you use it as the from address in Sendmail, and will instead replace it with that user@box###.bluehost.com string.

So essentially, you need to make sure, as LazyOne explains, that the sending script is adding a From: address@domain.com to the email's headers, and then ensure that address@domain.com is also set as a valid address in your Bluehost account. (I personally alway set them up and then forward them to one account, but that's certainly not necessary.)